# Is there a way to check if generic mapped entity is valid to be inserted or updated. EF 6

Tags: c#, excel, entity-framework, generics

I am loading  entities data from excel file, I need to validate the entity after create it from excel row, but I have more than one feature that offers the option of insert or update by excel file, so I would like to create something generic, something like ModelState.IsValid.

Does entity framework have something like this?

Comment: What does this validation entail?  Could you just use DataAnnotations on your model?  Is each row in Excel an individual entity or does it get decomposed into multiple entities?

Comment: By default, EF validates entities before saving changes.

Comment: Each row is an entity, I would like to check before send to insert.

I think I'll create model instead of entity, than I'll use TryValidateModel, if it's valid I create Entity and insert or update.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.getvalidationerrors(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: @GertArnold It's Good to know that this method exists, I would like to perform it without being in DAO layer, without entity being attached, but I already solved, by creating and validating viewmodel this way: ModelState.Clear(); TryValidateModel(model), all the errors are loaded in ModelState, then I read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by validating viewModel:

```
public ActionResult Insert(string data1, DateTime data2, int data3, bool 
 data4)
{
    Model model = new Model(data1, data2, data3, data4);

    ModelState.Clear(); 
    TryValidateModel(model);    
    LoadErrors();
}
```

All the errors are loaded in ModelState, then I read it:

```
private string[] LoadErrors()
{
    var errorList = ModelState
                 .Where(x => x.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
                 .ToDictionary(
                     kvp => kvp.Key,
                     kvp => kvp.Value.Errors.Select(e => 
                     e.ErrorMessage).ToArray()
                 );
    return errorList;
}
```